# Indexed generic (multi-type, single value) multidimensional array in c#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, generics, multidimensional-array

**Task**:
Read arrays (Trace data) from a binary file, where the amount of arrays, the lenght and the datatype is defined at the beginning of the file (header).

**Conditions**:

- Datatype could be different for every array, but one array has the same type.
- Each array has the same length, but the amount of arrays could be different.
- Datatype is defined as an number
- Informativ for code implementation -> Each Datatype has 4 bytes of length in the file

**Intention**:
I want an multidimensinal Arry (or List with arrays), where i could get and set every single value.

**Status**:
From my research I could allready build following code (Don't know if there are better ways!? Probably with arrays?).
(Best result of research: [Best way to design a multi-type object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629189/best-way-to-design-a-multi-type-object))

```
private abstract class TraceData
{

}

private class TraceData<T> : TraceData
{
    public T[] Data;

    public TraceData(UInt32 length)
    {
        Data = new T[length];
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return Data[index]; }
        set { Data[index] = value; }
    }
}

private class Traces
{
    public List<TraceData> Data;

    public Traces(TraceHeader Header, Byte[] file, int offset)
    {
        Data = new List<TraceData>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Header.DataAmount; i++)
        {
            TraceData tmp;
            switch (Header.DataTyp[i])
            {
                case 2:
                    tmp = new TraceData<SByte>(Header.DataLength);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tmp = new TraceData<Int16>(Header.DataLength);
                    break;
                //...
                default:
                    tmp = new TraceData<Int32>(Header.DataLength);
                    break;
            }
            Data.Add(tmp);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Header.DataLength; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Header.DataAmount; j++)
            {
                switch (Header.DataTyp[j])
                {
                    case 2:
                        Data[j][i] = (SByte)file[offset + i*Header.DataAmount*4 + j*4 + 3];
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Data[j][i] = BitConverter.ToUInt16(file, offset + i*Header.DataAmount*4 + j*4 + 2);
                        break;
                    //...
                    default:
                        Data[j][i] = BitConverter.ToUInt32(file, offset + i*Header.DataAmount*4 + j*4 + 0);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem**:
With that code I'm not able to index an element of the TraceData type.

Hope you could help.
THX

Comment: you need something like this?
var trace = new Traces(...);
var elem = trace[i,j];

Comment: "I'm not able to index an element of the TraceData type" -- Please be more specific. Show exactly the code you think/want should work but doesn't. State precisely in what way it doesn't work; what do you want it to do, and how is what it does different from that? If an error is generated, provide the _exact_ error message and state clearly when and where the error happens. Provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem

Comment: Yes you can't. `TraceData` doesn't have an indexer. Even if you provide one, you can't do it without boxing/unboxing.

Comment: This code above produce the errror at the indexed access: 'Data[j][i] = ...'. (I don't have it in Englich version)
What I want is mentioned at "Intention", but I don't know, if this code above is the best way for doing this (and also currently not working).
Code example above is complete except the data, namespace and so on, but to reproduce the errror this is not needed.
Are there better way for doing this? @PeterDuniho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess his point is to access the Data-Array of the generic Type TraceData, but he has only knowledge of objects of the Type of the abstract base-class TraceData. Like these calls do not work:

```
Data[j][i] = (SByte)file[offset + i*Header.DataAmount*4 + j*4 + 3];
```

Because *Data[j]* is of type TraceData. In any case you need to know the generic argument of the used type in that specific instance. So you could cast (example for SByte):

```
TraceData<SByte> SByteTraceData = (TraceData<SByte>)Data[j];
SByteTraceData[i] = (SByte)file[offset + i * Header.DataAmount * 4 + j * 4 + 3];
```

Comment: This made the trick I needed. THX. But is there a better way to store such data, with the mentioned conditions (and Task)? @PatrikEckebrecht

Comment: Your` TraceData<T>` class looks a bit like an Array-List, so you could have used `List<T>` instead. It will resize, if you need more space, not throw an exception for exceeding array-bounds, but that won't hurt you.

Comment: Concerning the `Traces`-class, I cannot really tell since I don't know your application in depth. Two-dimensional Array-access is never really a beauty.